# Kubernetes Volumes/PV vs Docker Named Volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes, volume

I am trying to understand how in Kubernetes we can achieve the capabilities of Docker Named Volumes. When I create an empty Docker named volume and mount it to my container, existing files in the container location gets copied into the host volume if it's empty, how can we achieve this behaviour wiht Kubernetes PV.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using local persistent volume to store data on the host machine

Follow the link: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/

Comment: ...even in a cloud environment where you may not have a “host machine” _per se_ (GKE, EKS, ...)?

Comment: You should be using AWSElasticBlockStore on AWS and GCEPersistentDisk on GKE

Comment: are you saying if I use AWSElasticBlockStore, then it will solve the purpose of showing/reflecting container files onto the empty volume.

Comment: if you bind pod volume to emptyDir then data will be available as long as the pod is alive. when pod is deleted then data gets lost. To retain the data it is better is bind the pod volume to external volume like EBS